# Javascript to move selected web text to MS Word

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ms-word

Im annoyed that this doesn't seem possible, but i wanted to check with the community to see if someone has developed a working version of something similar.

I'm a graduate student and spend a LOT of time online researching, and when I find that sweet paragraph that makes just the argument I've been searching for, I've gotta copy and paste it out of chrome (on mac os x) and into word (2011). I've built a "strip all formatting" macro that works well enough, but what i would like is a pipe from chrome into my open word document that gives me 1 key "send selection to word document" (like ~).

I've got the js working to get selected text and move it around, but i cannot seem to open the document i want to move the text into. Ideally, this would work as a chrome plugin (I've built them before), but I've seen no documentation about JS => Word on other platforms (obviously activeX controls dont work for me).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't think that's possible. Best solution I can think of is copying it to the clipboard and then alt-tab to word, ctrl v to paste (not sure of the correct shortcuts for mac, think it's just cmd instead of alt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an automator service to do this. Open Applications > Automator, and then create a service, which receives selected text (one of the built in defaults). This works in any app, and is accessible via the Services menu when you right click.

You can do this easily with TextEdit for example using these two actions:

```
Service receives selected text
New Textedit Document.
```

I've just tried it to confirm it. It can also copy rich text etc (including links) if you want. I imagine something similar is possible with word, and there is a built in service already to do the same if you have installed TextWrangler (another word processor).

Comment: Thanks, this is the direction i think ill go in.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is contained within the browser for security reasons, so you will not be able to do it with JavaScript.

The best thing that i can come up with is to write a 'bot' kinda thing that just coppy pastes, so not for in an extention.